# sqlplus spooling: How to get rid of first, empty line?

Tags: sql, sqlplus, spool, fixed-length-file

I'm doing the following spooling statement:

```
SET VERIFY OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET HEADING OFF
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SET TERM OFF
SPOOL &pathRelations
START scripts/relations.sql &parent
SPOOL OFF
SET TERM ON
```

The `scripts/relations.sql` file contains a simple `select` statement.

Unfortunately, the spooled file contains an empty line as the first one in the file. This line causes trouble in our framework.

Of course I could get rid of these line through `sed` but ain't there a way to suppress its creation in the first place?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`SET NEWPAGE NONE` is the correct answer.

`SET NEWPAGE 0` will cause a page feed, which is not what the OP wants.

Comment: Neither worked for me. Thanks anyway! However, setting heading to OFF will get rid of the empty line at the beginning at least, but I need the heading.

Comment: Best bet is to select your own header because SQLPLUS is not good at formatting headers.

Answer (score 1):

FYI set newpage does nothing if using set markup csv on.  Set markup csv on creates an LFCR at the beginning of the file which excel uses and adds a blank row.

Answer (score 0):

Working in TOAD, `set newpage none` didn't work for me. I still had an empty row between the header and the data. However, when I removed `set trimspool on`, the empty row went away.

Answer (score -1):

```
SET NEWPAGE 0
```

see [here](http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-sqlplus-set.html)